# Gridview data, not show value that is zero

Tags: c#, forms, gridview

I have a gridview that looks like this
[image]

I want to only show the values that is 1
Hide the 0
The data comes from SQL

This is the gridview

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;  " class="auto-style14">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Width="956px">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Förnamn" HeaderText="Förnamn" SortExpression="Förnamn" ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Efternamn" HeaderText="Efternamn" SortExpression="Efternamn" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" >
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Nickname" HeaderText="Nickname" SortExpression="Nickname" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" >
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Datum" HeaderText="Datum" SortExpression="Datum" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}">
                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Texas10_10" HeaderText="Texas 10/10" SortExpression="Texas10_10" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-ForeColor="Black">
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Texas25_25" HeaderText="Texas 25/25" SortExpression="Texas25_25" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-ForeColor="Black"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Texas50_50" HeaderText="Texas 50/50" SortExpression="Texas50_50" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-ForeColor="Black"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Texas_High_Stakes" HeaderText="Texas High Stakes" SortExpression="Texas_High_Stakes" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-ForeColor="Black"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Omaha10_10" HeaderText="Omaha 10/10" SortExpression="Omaha10_10" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-ForeColor="Black"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Omaha25_25" HeaderText="Omaha 25/25" SortExpression="Omaha25_25" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-ForeColor="Black"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Omaha50_50" HeaderText="Omaha 50/50" SortExpression="Omaha50_50" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-ForeColor="Black"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Omaha_High_Stakes" HeaderText="Omaha High Stakes" SortExpression="Omaha_High_Stakes" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-ForeColor="Black"/>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Maroon" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CashGameConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Förnamn], [Efternamn], [Nickname], [Datum], [Texas10_10], [Texas25_25], [Texas50_50], [Omaha10_10], [Omaha25_25], [Omaha50_50], [Texas_High_Stakes], [Omaha_High_Stakes] FROM [tblStoGame] ORDER BY [Datum]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        
    </div>
```

Hope someone has any idea for me

Cheers
Ace

Comment: When you say hide - does that mean just show nothing and keep the column intact?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: Try creating a rowdatabound event for grid and paste in this code - this should work but untested - if (e.Row.DataItem == "0")
        e.Row.DataItem = ""; should work if its a string

Comment: Thank
I got it to work with this
                    if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Equals("0"))
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "";
                    }